# Moodledata on EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, moodle, amazon-efs

I am in the process of setting up moodle an on AWS.

I am a little bit confused about where to put my moodledata directory as I will need to read/write to this directory from multiple EC2 instances. I see that EFS is the best option but also read that it is very slow. Is there better options ?

Comment: I suggest you try EFS first and see if it meets your needs. It would be quite easy to set up spot instances to test EBS and EFS to see if there's any practical difference in performance. If it's not good enough come back and tell us, then we can help some more. There's no other magically better solution, you might have to consider replication, setting up your own file server, that kind of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim. I will try EFS first and let you know if I need your more help.